# Configuring Order of JmsListener Execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

If I have more than one `@JmsListener` method in a Spring Boot application is there a way to explicitly declare either listener to consume all its messages from its queue before the other?

In other words, if I have

```
@JmsListener(destination = "queueOne") 
    public void processOrder1(String message) {. . .}

@JmsListener(destination = "queueTwo") 
    public void processOrder2(String message) {. . .}
```

is there configuration available to have `processOrder1()` run to completion, shut it down, then have `processOrder2()` run? Or will `processOrder2()` always execute after `processOrder1()`(which is what the debugger suggests)? Or are they somehow running separately independent of each other?

If they cannot be configured in such a way I'd like to know why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with configuration - each listener gets its own independent asynchronous listener container.

You could configure the container factory with `autoStartup` set to `false` and start each container programmatically - get a reference to the container from the container registry using the listener's `id` attribute and `start()/stop()` it.

One difficulty is how you would "know" that the first one has completed its work.

Comment: I take the initial queue depth of the queue the listener is on and decrement that value for each message that comes in. So ideally when the count is zero, the message being processed must be the last. This how I determine to shut down my single JmsListener. But a requirement came through that I'll need more queues.

Comment: So, in theory, when I know that a particular JmsListener is finished, I can call stop on that one, and then basically start on the next one I'd like to run? Though I may have missed the asynchronous bit when digging through the spring docs...That may work to my advantage as well